# Next project rendering and working very slow

Tags: node.js, next.js

Nextjs 13 works very slow and render pages multiple times?

Can anyone help me with this?

Nextjs 13 works very slow and render pages multiple times?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.